# How much overhead does `python -X importtime` add?

Tags: python, cpython

Does anyone know how much slower running `python -X importtime [module or file]` is vs. `python [module or file]`?

I'm wondering if it's a bad idea to run `python -X importtime` for production code. The goal is to monitor how slow the imports are in production code, to identify opportunities to remove unnecessary imports.

Answer (score 2):

On one of my windows systems with a simple file:

test.py

```
import pandas
import numpy
import requests
```

When I run

```
Measure-Command {python -Ximporttime test.py > foo.txt 2>&1}
```

I get results in the range of 670ms

When I run

```
Measure-Command {python test.py > foo.txt 2>&1}
```

I get results in the range of 640ms

You can decide if that overhead is worth it or not in your use case. My sense is that if 30ms is a deal breaker then perhaps python was not the right solution to begin with.